# How to set timeout to external URL?

Tags: apex, visualforce, timeout

I want to know how to set timeout to external link.Here is my code.

```
public PageReference confirm2(){
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('http://www.google.com');
    return pageRef;
    
    }

<apex:commandButton value="test" action="{!confirm2}"/>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to set the timeout in this scenario; the browser and/or Operating System will have a specific timeout limit for the server to respond. If you want to be able to control the timeout, you need to perform the callout in Apex or JavaScript.

```
// Apex
public String confirm2() {
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
  req.setEndpoint('https://www.google.com');
  req.setTimeout(1000); // 1 second
  req.setMethod('GET');
  HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
  return res.getBody();
}
```

---

```
// JavaScript
async doCallout(timeout) {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(()=>controller.abort(),timeout);
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=1',
      {
        mode: 'cors',
        signal: controller.signal
      });
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    const content = await response.text();
    this.template.querySelector('div').innerText = content;
  } catch(e) {
    this.template.querySelector('div').innerText = `Error: ${e.message || e}`;
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/j7h2qVfoRNMwt7ZFCrRt/src/app.js?p=stories).

Note that this requires that the server you wish to connect to must support CORS.